# Does GooglePlay search show different results for different cities?

Tags: google-play-store, search

I have a few different Android apps and for some reason, one is very heavily downloaded in India and Nigeria.

And the others have at least 35% US downloads.

Would anyone know whether the GooglePlay search is different in different countries? Or is it the same everywhere?

Thanks!

Comment: maan, a persone is saying that i gave you the answer and you mark him as the correct answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is different. Just like Google search Google play search  uses different settings for every person, just like rat2000 said.

Comment: thank you. Would you know how to check an app's ranking for different countries?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can check your ranking for different countries but if you have this option it should be in the Google play developer console.

Comment: you cannot check app's ranking for diferent countries

Answer (score 2):

It is not the same. for countries. Google search is not the same for you and a friend or your neighbor. 
Google keeps data for every person that uses that services and determines what he might like or might not like. At a country level based on all the search that you made and the citizens it decides what you or another citizen might like.
 Basically it is all very connected and there are very powerful algorithms that determine what a user might need based on the location he is, the nationalyti, the previous searches, his friend searches, everything matters more or less.

Comment: I didn't mean Google search. I meant GooglePlay search. Do you know if GooglePlay search is different across different countries?

Comment: It is the same. all services are interconnected. if you make a search in google play for a specific game, next time you use google search it will know that you like that type of games, and it goes the other way around.